# How to override and reference variables? Migrating from LESS to Sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

### Bootstrap 3 and LESS

**Bootstrap 4** compared to **Bootstrap 3** has not changed in terms of directory/file structure.
What changed is the abandonment of the **LESS** preprocessor.

Well, I'm glad of this decision but there's one huge difference between Sass and Less in how they treat variables.

---

### Overriding and referencing Bootstrap 4 Sass variables

LESS has something called lazy variable evaluation.

Let's say I need to override variables in `bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss` and at the same time reference those that are declared in it.

Simple example:

```sass
$mycolor: #f4f9f1;
$body-bg: $mycolor;
$body-color: $grey-900;
```

This does not compile because `$grey-900` does not exist yet.
It can be solved by declaring `$grey-900` inside our own overrides. But that means we have to check what constant Bootstrap uses for `grey-900` each time bootstrap is updated.

In v3 LESS implementation it wasn't even an issue to reference an existing variable from `variables.less` -- because of that lazy variable evaluation. Now in v4, in order to reference an existing variable the whole `_bootstrap.scss` must be copied and pasted into project's directory:

```sass
// _my-bootstrap.scss
/*
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2
 */
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';

@import 'custom-variables';

@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/root';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/print';
...
```

Here we import the required `_functions.scss` and `_variables.scss` then import our `_custom-variables.scss` and then the rest.

The drawback is obvious -- now after every update one will have to compare the `_my-bootstrap.scss` file with the `_bootstrap.scss` and apply the differences because optional components could be added/renamed/deprecated/removed.

---

## The solution (rejected)

I've made a proposal in form of a Pull Request https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/24802
The idea is to split the monolith `boostrap.scss` into two separate stylesheets -- **required** and **optional**.
Unfortunately, it was declined by @mdo without explanation, IDK why. Is Mark Otto the only one who makes architectural decisions? IDK.

If the PR would be merged, a user would be able to easily override the variables by including only two files from node_modules:

```sass
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-required";
@import "custom-variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-optional";
```

In case of a small project -- when there's no need to reference existing variables -- one can always go with the old way, leveraging the `!default` feature of `Sass`.

```sass
@import "custom-variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

It could be a win-win solution for any kind of projects

In the [Getting started with theming section of the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/), there's already a clear separation between Required and Optional stylesheets.

---

## Another solution exists?

Maybe I'm the only one who needs to reference existing variables or maybe there's another solution exists that I'm not aware of?